# How to get all attributes on an XML node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

How do I get all the attributes that exist on a XML node? For example, I have the following XML:

```
<item id="100">
  <defaults width="10" height="100" post="true">
</item>
```

I would like to get the names and values on the defaults node.

Here is some starter code:

```
if (item.defaults) {
    var attributes:Object = item.defaults.@*; // found in another post

    for each (var value:String in attributes) {
        trace("value "+value); // prints 10,100,true
    }
    for (var property:String in attributes) {
        trace("property "+property); // prints 0,1,2 - I need to know the names
    }
}
```

I found the answer:

```
if (item.defaults) {
    attributes = item.defaults.attributes();
    attributesLength = attributes.length();
    defaults = {};

    for each (var attribute:Object in attributes) {
        propertyName = String(attribute.name());
        defaults[propertyName] = String(attribute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortest one I could think of:

```
var defaults : Object = {};
if (item.defaults)
    for each (var att : XML in item.defaults.@*)
        defaults["" + att.name ()] = "" + att.valueOf ();
```

Comment: I marked your answer correct because you included the code to convert the name and value to String. Without this there are some issues with checking values and comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to get ya going:

```
for each (var k:XML in xml.defaults.@*)
{
    trace(k.name(), k.toXMLString());
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can convert the XML into Object

```
 public function xmlToObject(value:String):Object 
        {
                var xmlStr:String = value.toString();
                var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(xmlStr);
                var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
                var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
                return resultObj;
            }
```

this is the function that converts xml into Object you just need to pass XML as a string and it will returns the Object.. now its easy for you to fetch data from Object.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var xml:XML = <item id="100"><defaults width="10" height="100" post="true"/></item>;

if (xml.defaults) 
{
    var attributes:XMLList = xml.defaults.attributes();

    for each (var prop:Object in attributes) 
    {
        trace(prop.name() + " = " + prop); 
    }
}
```